# process's virtual memory size on different machines

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, virtual-memory

Does virtual memory of process can have different size on different machines (CPU, memory)?
The process does the same job on both machines.

The platform is RHEL 5.3 (kernel 2.6.18) and the process is C++ compiled by gcc (4.1.2).

Comment: Are you talking about the amount of RAM in use, or the amount of virtual memory available? Are you talking about machines that have the same architecture/kernel/compiler, or do they have different architectures?

Comment: I'm talking about virtual memory of the process (VIRT column in top).
The machines, if I'm correct, are indentiacal but have different amount of RAM - 4 and 16 G. Kernel and compiler are same.

Answer (score 1):

If the OS/kernel, or any loaded modules (or even the installed `.so` version of the g++ standard library) were different between the hosts, I don't see that you could necessarily rely on the virtual memory footprint being identical.

Even if all of those things were identical, but the total memory in the machine was different, it still seems possible that the kernel memory manager could behave in a different way such that the memory size would still differ.